i dont know why and where Change My Body Data in BasicdeliverEventArgs Object in My Code
I want to process my queue in multithread using threadpool .
i read (BasicdeliverEventArgs Object) queue from rabbbitmq and DataQueue.Enqueue(Object)
after that Process Queue
this is my code:
ProcessQueue(Object obj)
   {
     BasicdeliverEventArgs e=new BasicdeliverEventArgs();
     e=(BasicdeliverEventArgs) obj
     var e.Body.ToArray();
     ByteArraySerializer cnv=new ByteArraySerializer();
     var dto=cnv.Deserialize<MyClass>(body);
     try
       {
        err= Repository.Database.Insert(dto); //Insert dto To SqlServer Database
        if (err==null)
        Consol.Writeln("Success Sent");
        else
        FailQueue.Enqueue(obj);  
      // My Problem : Some Time Body In obj Change Automaticly out of my  Code!!!
      }
      catch(Exeption ex)
      {
       Consol.Writeln("Error Occoured:"+ex);
      }

   }

in my code i never change obj Object in Code but If err return from Databse my obj changhed
i trace more than 100 My code But Not Recognize How and where Change Obj.....

Your code would not even compile. Please provide actual code you have and please clarify your question with clear statement what is the problem.

i think that find the problem. when i enqueue BasicdeliverEventArgs  to DataQueue.Enqueue(Object)  because i send an  refrence Value Object to queue
